# Theorem with an example

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis

i have this theorem [image]
[image]

in the paper they gives an example:
[image]

but here $H_1$ is not satisfied !

How to correct it please?

Comment: The paper is http://www.academia.edu/4591584/Multiple_solutions_of_some_nonlinear_fourth-order_beam_equations

Comment: This was simultaneously posted at MSE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760139/theorem-with-an-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.academia.edu/4591584/Multiple_solutions_of_some_nonlinear_fourth-order_beam_equations

I think you can change the example to $f(t,u)=81u+4015\sin u+tu$. Then H1 holds, while for H2, the integral is 
$$F(t,u)=({81+t\over 2})u^2+4015(1-\cos u)$$
and so is bounded as indicated with $\alpha={81+1\over 2}=41<\pi^4/2$ and $\beta=2\cdot 4015$. Finally, $$f'_u(t,u)=81+4015\cos u+t$$ so $f'_u(t,0)=4096+t$, for which $m=2$ gives the desired inequality in H3. At least if I got all the details right.

Whether or not this is what was intended, or if the modified example is of any relevance, is a different matter.